# Matrix Data Extraction MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm currently stuck on this problem. I have a variable with data as shown in this picture (. Since I did not write the software myself I cannot change the format of the data. I'd like to extract all the values in the "z" direction or the third element (the one with 101 terms, refer to the picture). is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

[image: Variable with data I'd like to extract]

I've tried treating it as a matrix with three variables if that makes sense? trying to say for example:

a = P.E3D(75,75,n)

in a while loop but no dice. Get the error "Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds. Index must not exceed 1." I do get 101 copies of the set of data with

a = P.E3D(1,1)

Although I really should've expected that. I've failed to find anything talking about it online so I've turned to here now.

Comment: you need `a = P.E3D(75,75,:);`

Comment: If `P` is a struct array with N elements, then `P.E3D` will return a comma-separated list of N values that you cannot index in. Maybe this is what is happening? We don’t know enough about your data to answer this question.